# adding a parameter to an url on apache httpd to be received in a spring application running on jboss

Tags: java, linux, spring, apache, jboss

I have a apache httpd server receiving the requests for a website. this website will have two domains( example.com and example.pt).

What I want to do is to, depending on the virtual host used (com or pt) add a parameter to the url to change the locale of the language, something like index.html?lang=pt or index.html=lang=en.

The apache server redirects by proxy pass to a jboss server using AJP.

what is the cleanest way to do this and that can be easily incremented to support more domains?

Comment: php can do this at apache httpd